# Perl: say and print, one more newline than expected?

Tags: perl

Why this program creates **2** newlines, one is from `say` and the other is from where ?

```
use feature 'say';

my $s1  = 'X';
my $s2  = 'Y';
say join ("0",@{[$s1, $s2]});
```

**EDIT** these are the 2 newlines:

```
$ perl b.pl
X0Y

user$
```

Comment: *"Why this program creates 2 newlines"* - It does not. I've tried exactly the code included in your question and it results in `"X0Y\n"`, i.e. a single new line at the end as expected.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Please see my edit. One newline is after Y and the other before `user`.

Comment: Like I said, I run exactly your code and there is only a single new line. Maybe the output is from outside your program. If you have `xxd` try to pipe the output through it  to see the details of what the program produces, i.e. `perl b.pl | xxd`

Comment: @SteffenUllrich It works fine, I have `less`.

Comment: *"It works fine, I have less"* - I'm not sure what you mean with this. What exactly means "works fine" and how does `less` help?

Comment: I have a linux-style command `perl b.pl | less` instead of your `xxd`. X0Y
(END)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232453/discussion-between-steffen-ullrich-and-user2925716).

Comment: This de-referencing of an anonymous array that you make on the fly is very strange. `@{ [ ... ] }`. It is also totally unnecessary. In fact, I struggle to find a situation where this construct would be useful.

Comment: @TLP Some people use it for interpolating func calls.  `say "Output: @{[ f() ]}";` I'm not fond it even there.

Answer (score 1):

It does not output two line feeds.

```
$ perl -e'
   use feature "say";

   my $s1  = "X";
   my $s2  = "Y";
   say join ("0",@{[$s1, $s2]});
' | od -c
0000000   X   0   Y  \n
0000004
```

I do see the same blank line as you

```
{1} ikegami@tribble [~]$ perl -e'
   use feature "say";

   my $s1  = "X";
   my $s2  = "Y";
   say join ("0",@{[$s1, $s2]});
'
X0Y

{2} ikegami@tribble [~]$
```

But that's because I have my prompt set to add a blank line.

```
$ echo "$PS1"
\[\e]0;\u@\h:\w\a\]\n${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot) }{\!} \[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\] [\[\033[01;36m\]\w\[\033[00m\]]\$
                   ^^
```